# How to tell if an empty XML node has been found?

Tags: xml, go

I have XML like this:

```
<list>
<entry><string>...</string><string>...</string></entry>
<entry><string>...</string><string></string></entry>
<entry><string>...</string><null/></entry>
<entry><string>...</string><string>...</string><null/></entry>
</list>
```

How to tell that I had a `<null/>` element? This is the struct I'm trying to work with:

```
type Entry struct {
    Values []string `xml:"string"`
    Null   string   `xml:"null"`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK that was embarrassing :)

```
type Entry struct {
    Values []string `xml:"string"`
    Nulls  []string `xml:"null"`
}
```